# javascript jsx map on result of logical or

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I want to have an expression like:

```
 <td>
   {phones.map((phone, j) => 
     <p>{this.renderPhone(phone)}</p>
   )}
 </td>
```

but phones array may not always be defined.

Is there something like this possible:

```
(phones || []).map()
```

Comment: Yes. Just do that.

Comment: Why won't your `phones` array always be defined?

Comment: @Hamms I tried that and got an error:

Comment: @Michael contact object is coming from an API which I don't control. If the contact does not have any phone numbers stored in their record, this object will not be present

Comment: @swami what error did you get?

Comment: @Hamms  TypeError: (contact.phones || []).map is not a function
    at eval (webpack:///./src/ContactList.js?:120:42)
    at Array.map (native)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check it like below,

```
const self = this;
 <td>
   {phones !== undefined ? phones.map((phone, j) => 
     <p>{this.renderPhone(phone)}</p>
     )
   : null}
 </td>
```

Comment: Arrow functions automatically bind the lexical value of `this`, so yes, the OP can still use `this.renderPhone` inside the arrow function.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions